# How can I connect OS X 10.8.2 to Windows Server 2008?

Tags: macos, windows-server-2008, smb

I'm trying to connect from my Mac OS X 10.8.2 to Windows Server 2008.

I've tried

```
smb://ServerName/ShareName  
smb://DOMAIN;User@ServerName/ShareName
```

mentioned on the [Apple docs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568), but it keeps giving me

> There was a problem connecting to the server "fileserver". Check the
>   server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have
>   problem...

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is your server called `fileserver`? If you `ping fileserver` from a Terminal does it resolve to valid IP address and get responses?

Comment: Sometime back came across similar issue resolved in apple community, try this [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2553218?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: yes @Johnsyweb, it's called "fileserver", I ping it and I tried the IP 
(smb://192.168...)
but i got the same problem :S

Comment: SunEric, I've read this post before, and I tried to connect to the direct IP, but nothing works

Comment: 10.8 and SMB shares on Windows server aren't working at all. I have at least 500 Mac from 10.5 to now 10.8 running on our network and haven't had any problems with Mac's getting to Windows shares until OS 10.8. I really don't think it's a ping thing that he having a problem with, it's the new SMBX that OS 10.8 uses. If anyone find a fix please put it out here because We need it as soon as possible. If you search this problem you will see that it has a lot of people upset as well as me. I'm working on it and if I find a fix I'll put it there and I hope everyone will because this is driving me c